# Animation: Jquery on start?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this script in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var scrollSpeed = 70;      // Speed in milliseconds
    var step = 1;              // How many pixels to move per step
    var current = 0;           // The current pixel row
    var imageHeight = 2580;    // Background image height
    var headerHeight = 300;    // How tall the header is.

    //The pixel row where to start a new loop
    var restartPosition = -(imageHeight - headerHeight);

    function scrollBg() {
        //Go to next pixel row.
        current -= step;
        //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
        if (current == restartPosition){
            current = 0;
        }
        //Set the CSS of the header.
        $('#wrapper1').css("background-position","0 "+current+"px");
    }

    //Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
    var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);   
</script>
```

the background is moving, how can i set an stoptimer, that the script runs after 10 seconds? i mean that the anmiation starts after 10 seconds.

Thanks
Carsten

Comment: You want to this animation to start after 10 seconds after the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function, like this: `setTimeout('var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);', 10000);`.

The ***10000*** is the time in miliseconds it should wait before executing the expression, which is 10 seconds.

Comment: Please do not use strings in a `setTimeout`, but rather pass a function instead.